# How to Disable the very next weekends in jQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

In an order page I want to implement a calendar, in which, if the user is ordering on friday after 10am, then block the following saturday and sunday in delivery date calendar.   Here is a sample code I am trying, but not working as intended.

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = dt.getDay();
    var hour = dt.getHours();
    if (day == 4) {
        // i think, here i want to put the code to disable days
    }
}
```

If I use something like this

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    var dt = new Date();
    var hour = dt.getHours();
    return [(day != 5 && day != 6)];
}
```

I am able to disable Sat and Sun days, but this will disable all the Sat and Sun days. I wnat to disable only the very next Sat n Sun days to be disabled. Also I can get current Hour in var hour, So where should I use the condition to check if the hour is greater than 10am, I am using something like this but not working

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var dt = new Date();
    var hour = dt.getHours();
    var day = date.getDay();
    if (day == 4 && hour >= 10) {
        return [(day != 5 && day != 6)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't Friday be `day==5` since 0 is Sunday? Also, which 10am are you going by, the time on the visitor's machine or the time on your server?

Comment: @j08691 - sorry for that, day==5, at present I am going by machine time. can you give me a clue how to use the server time, i am using PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `beforeShowDay` function, check the current date to see if it is a Friday and after 10am. If this is true then you also need to check if the `date` passed as argument is the next Saturday or Sunday:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      // date (Friday March 13 2015 10:00 AM) is hardcoded for testing
      var now = new Date(2015, 3 - 1, 13, 10, 0, 0, 0);
      if (now.getDay() === 5 && now.getHours() >= 10) {
        var now_plus_1 = new Date(now.getTime()); now_plus_1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); now_plus_1.setDate(now_plus_1.getDate() + 1);
        var now_plus_2 = new Date(now.getTime()); now_plus_2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); now_plus_2.setDate(now_plus_2.getDate() + 2);
        return [date.getTime() !== now_plus_1.getTime() && date.getTime() !== now_plus_2.getTime(), ""];
      }
      return [true, ""];
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.min.css");

body { font-size: smaller; }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var dt = new Date(),
            day = dt.getDay(),
            hour = dt.getHours(),
            twoDaysFrmNow = new Date().setDate(dt.getDate() + 2);
        return [!(day == 5 && hour >= 10 && date <= twoDaysFrmNow &&  date > dt)];
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey brthr, you code is simple and works, but this will disable the same dates in following moths also, I mean for today this moth it works ok, 21st Sat and 22nd  Sun days will be disabled, but next month 21st and 22nd also will be disabled, is there any workkaround.

Comment: Good catch @SalihK. Should be fixed now :). the setDate function handles wrapping around months. So if it were the 30th, it would set the date to the first of the next month (in a 31 day month).

Answer (score 0):

> beforeShowDayType: Function( Date date )
>
> Default: null
>
> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array
>   with:
>
> [0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable [1]:
>   a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default
>   presentation [2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
>
> The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is
>   displayed.

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
     var day = dt.getDay();
                         var hour = dt.getHours();
                        if( day == 4) {
                           // this is an example of how to use
                            //first parameter is disable or not this date
                            //second parameter is the class you want to add ( jquery will remove the click listener, but you probebly want to style it like this date is not available
                            //third optional tootltip like 'closed on weekends'
                             return [false,'disabled','weekend']
                        }

                    }
```